Renew command in section and subsection
How do I change a section and a subsection to have something like this:
A) A.i) A.ii) B) B.i) B.ii)
I tried with \renewcommand:
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section})}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\roman{subsection})}
But I have: A) A).i) A).ii) B) B).i) B).ii)
I have no idea how to get rid of parentheses after a section in a subsection.

Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead edit your question to give a small compilable example document that shows what you're doing.

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{section}\roman{subsection})}?

Since you include the parenthesis as part of the \thesection, you can't use it in the definition of \thesubsection so instead you just need to use \Alph{section}:
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section})}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{section}.\roman{subsection})}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{A susection}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}

As egreg mentions in his answer, it's better not to put too much formatting into the counter definitions. Another way to adjust the title headings without needing to know much about the internals is to use the titlesec package. It provides a \titlelabel command that allows you to style the label easily:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle)\space}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\roman{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{A susection}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}


I wouldn't add the parentheses to \thesection and \thesubsection, but rather to the section header making command. The less you hardwire in the counter's representation, the better.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname)\quad}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\roman{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section} \label{test1}
\subsection{A subsection} \label{test2}
\subsection{A susection}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\ref{test1} and \ref{test2}

\end{document}


With this approach, the cross references won't have the parenthesis. If you want them, then it's easy as well.
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname)\quad}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\roman{subsection}}
\labelformat{section}{#1)}
\labelformat{subsection}{#1)}

\begin{document}

\section{A section} \label{test1}
\subsection{A subsection} \label{test2}
\subsection{A susection}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\ref{test1} and \ref{test2}

\end{document}


